# jQuery only need hover to affect one image at a time

Tags: jquery, hover, flip

I am going to have a number of images with a picture on the front and information on the back. I have it set up to flip on hover, but flipping one seems to flip the other one as well (for this example I'm only using two images with a black front and blue back)

How can I change the code so that it will only flip the one image that the mouse is hovering over?

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var margin=$('.front').width()/2;
    var width=$('.front').width();
    var height=$('.front').height();

    $('.back').stop().css({width:'0px',height:''+height+'px',
                           marginLeft:''+margin+'px',opacity:'0.5'});

    $('.front').hover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({width:'0px',height:''+height+'px',
                                marginLeft:''+margin+'px',opacity:'0.5'},
                               {duration:500});
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $('.back').stop().animate({width:''+width+'px',height:''+height+'px',
                                       marginLeft:'0px',opacity:'1'},
                                      {duration:500});
        },500);
    });

    $('.back').hover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({width:'0px',height:''+height+'px',
                                marginLeft:''+margin+'px',opacity:'0.5'},
                               {duration:500});
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $('.front').stop().animate({width:''+width+'px',height:''+height+'px',
                                        marginLeft:'0px',opacity:'1'},
                                       {duration:500});
        },500);
    });
});
```

**Markup:**

```
<div id="container">
    <img class="front" id="image1" src="images/front_image.png" alt="" />
    <img class="back" id="image2" src="images/back_image.png" alt="" />
</div>

<div id="container">
    <img class="front" id="image3" src="images/front_image.png" alt="" />
    <img class="back" id="image4" src="images/back_image.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {position: relative; width: 140px; height: 200px; display: inline-block;}
.front {position: absolute; cursor: pointer;}
.back {display: none; position: absolute; cursor: pointer;}
```

Comment: `id` should be unique

Comment: I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdcds/1/) containing the information you're giving us. It doesn't seem to break.

Comment: Thanks, Loyalar. But when you hover over one of the images in your fiddle the image disappears completely.

Comment: If you want css solution you can look at this http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your `setTimeout` call, you're animating **everything** in the class. You need to animate only the object that is being hovered. You'll need to assign a unique class to each image pair and then grab the unique class during the hover function. Maybe something like this:

HTML:

```
<img class="front card1" id="image1"...
<img class="back card1" id="image2"...
```

Javascript:

```
$('.front').hover(function(){
    ...
    var cardClass = $(this).attr('class').match(/card\d/);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $('.back.' + cardClass).stop().animate...
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, GreatBigBore. That seemed to do the trick as far as spinning only the one that's being hovered on, but when it spins once it's gone. It's supposed to spin to the next image.

Answer (score 0):

As someone pointed out in a comment, you may want to consider using css to accomplish this as it's much cleaner.  However, to fix this javascript I think you should consider changing the approach from using window.SetTimeout() to using both handlers of the hover method.  There are two parameters for the hover method:

```
.hover( handlerIn(eventObject), handlerOut(eventObject) )
```

These are just shortcuts to the mouseenter/mouseleave events.  You also need to define variables to be of the proper scope in the functions.  Similar to this/that I've defined a var for front in the mouseenter handler and a var for back in the mouseleave handler.  Both are to use in their respective complete functions.  To obtain the proper front and back images you need to use a relative selector.  In this case I've used children of the div.  Finally, to avoid the back image getting "stuck" I've called stop before animate and also on the opposite image before starting the first animation in each event handler.  Here is the code ([original fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PFXY4) or [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PFXY4/1)):

**css**

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}
.front {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.back {
    /*display: none;*/
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="front" src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=front1" alt="" />
    <img class="back" src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=back1" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img class="front" src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=front2" alt="" />
    <img class="back" src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=back2" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img class="front" src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=front3" alt="" />
    <img class="back" src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=back3" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img class="front" src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=front4" alt="" />
    <img class="back" src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=back4" alt="" />
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.container').each(function () {
        var front = $(this).children('.front');
        var back = $(this).children('.back');
        var height = front.height();
        var width = front.width();
        var margin = width / 2;

        front.data('w', width);
        front.data('h', height);

        $(this).css({
            width: width + 'px',
            height: height + 'px'
        });

        back.stop().css({
            width: '0px',
            height: '' + height + 'px',
            marginLeft: '' + margin + 'px',
            opacity: '0.5'
        });
    });

    $('.container').hover(function () {
        var back = $(this).children('.back');
        var front = $(this).children('.front');
        var width = front.data('w');
        var height = front.data('h');
        var margin = width / 2;

        back.stop();
        front.stop().animate({
            width: '0px',
            height: height + 'px',
            marginLeft: margin + 'px',
            opacity: '0.5'
        }, 500, function () {
            back.stop().animate({
                width: width + 'px',
                height: height + 'px',
                marginLeft: '0px',
                opacity: '1'
            }, 500);
        });
    },

    function () {
        var front = $(this).children('.front');
        var back = $(this).children('.back');
        var width = front.data('w');
        var height = front.data('h');
        var margin = width / 2;

        front.stop();
        back.stop().animate({
            width: '0px',
            height: height + 'px',
            marginLeft: margin + 'px',
            opacity: '0.5'
        }, 500, function () {
            front.stop().animate({
                width: width + 'px',
                height: height + 'px',
                marginLeft: '0px',
                opacity: '1'
            }, 500);
        });
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:** updated javascript to allow for any size image.

Answer (score 0):

I try to use `.each` and `$(this)` like this:

```
$('.front').each(function(){

  $(this).hover(function(){

    Whatever
  })
})
```